# How to tack real world object using iphone camera?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am iOS developer. I am new with doing object tracking feature. I have searched many links based on tracking real objects. But I have found many links like image tracking, image matching and all. Likewise I would like to track the real world objects.And also I have gone through a site below:
http://developers.arlab.com/me
It helps a lot for tracking images, image matching etc. But not specified any object tracking. If anybody suggesting good tutorial or having any sample source code of object tracking, please share.

Advance Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OpenCV framework for **Object Tracking**. There are many nice tutorial and documentation on internet.

Below i have listed some.Please check if this helps you

**Official Site**

OpenCV is released under a BSD license and hence it’s free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android. OpenCV was designed for computational efficiency and with a strong focus on real-time applications...

http://opencv.org/

You can download the SDK from here

**Demo Github project**

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv

https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing

These are some examples you can find many more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Expecting more support from you in the future also

Comment: Do you having any sample source code of object tracking project. I need to refer it. I having image tracking and all.

Comment: https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial this link contains all the samples.

Comment: If u think ,This post was helpful then accept the answer